# How to encode property transfer value in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to retrieve the value from the GET method and using property transfer to transfer on the content of the POST method using SOAPUI PRO.  When the value transfer, seems like it contains different characters (Like /,+,etc) . So I have to encode the value to html (%).  Does anyone know how to set that in SOAPUI PRO.

[image]
Response:
[image]

GET RESPONSE :[image]

html codes continues and then these are the info I need encode

[image]

Comment: Can you please add an example of input and output? or some more context?

Comment: right now it is parsing like: 2i7SYxYoXMCbwYjET/rCErZYgnGjaVjuel8+q but the way if we use html encoder it should be like 2i7SYxYoXMCbwYjET%rCErZYgnGjaVjuel8%q

Comment: Please show the raw response?

Comment: @Rao I attached the picture

Comment: I was asking the raw response of GET call

Comment: @Rao I attached the GET call response. it is contain long html code. So I attached the info that I need to use it for the parsing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134495/discussion-between-rao-and-user3174886).